# Calculating Number of week with a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, week-number

I am planing to make a scheduling application.
According to the business logic the first day of the week starts from the moment you finish your vacation..For Example:
If my vacation ended years and I would start my work from today..It would be counted as my 1st week at work but actually according to the calender its the 25.I would be again eligible for a vacation on week 40 but not from the actual calender but from the system that is calculating my weeks from the last time i Came back from one.
I need some help on how to calculate it and how it works when the new years week is 1.

Can some one please suggest me a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Please rephrase this to include an actual question. It would make it much more understandable.

Comment: Sample data would be good, too - inputs and expected outputs, along with what you've already tried.

Comment: There's no confusion. You do a pre-check on the dates ~ pseudo-like: `if not January => calculate relative startWeek`

Comment: Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int weeks=0;
  DateTime firstdayback = Convert.ToDateTime ("2013-06-01");
            weeks = DateTime.Now.Subtract(firstdayback).Days / 7;
            Console.WriteLine(weeks);
```

Persistence Pays B*s !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class Week of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) which supports various week calculations:

```
TimeCalendar calendar = new TimeCalendar(
    new TimeCalendarConfig { YearWeekType = YearWeekType.Iso8601 } );
Week week = new Week( new DateTime( 2012, 01, 01 ), calendar );
Console.WriteLine( "week #: ", week.WeekOfYear );
```